# How to stop mplayer from moving mouse pointer?

Tags: linux, mouse, mplayer

I noticed that mplayer moves mouse cursor every 10 seconds:

```
ltrace -e '!read,select,vsnprintf,ioctl,XSync,XShmPutImage,malloc,memcpy,free,XNextEvent,XPending,sws_scale_ordered,pp_postprocess,avcodec_decode_video,strcmp,gettimeofday,nanosleep' -p  `pidof mplayer`
XWarpPointer(0x8ce9480, 0x1800002, 0, 0, 0)                                  = 1
XWarpPointer(0x8ce9480, 0x1800002, 0, 0, 0)                                  = 1
...
```

Probably it is to trick possible screensaver. There are no `-stop-xscreensaver` or mouse-related options speicfied.

How to turn off such behaviour?

Comment: Which version of `mplayer`?

Comment: `MPlayer 1.0rc3-4.4.4 (C) 2000-2009 MPlayer Team`, Debian Squeeze default.